# Firestore onsnapshot detach is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am using fire store with angular and used onsnapshot method. To remove the listener I did the similar way what docs is suggesting but still I am receiving the real time updates. Any suggestions?

```
unsubscribe:any;

this.unsubscribe = db.collection("cities")

    .onSnapshot(function (){
      // Respond to data
    });

this.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Try to use the exact syntax as in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Comment: I am not sure how const variable can be accessible in other method of page, like I wanted to detach when user is moving away from the page in onDestroy method.

Comment: It is not necessary to access it from another method: It is only necessary to call the method where the const is declared.